# Cross room communication puzzle

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I try to send some message across rooms. I have:

server.js

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8081);

var chat = io
  .of('/chat')
  .on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('chatTestEmit1', function(d) {
        console.log('>> chatTestEmit1 >> '+JSON.stringify(d));
        console.log(io.sockets.manager.rooms);
        socket.to('/news').emit('newsTestEmit1', d);
    });
  });

var news = io
  .of('/news')
  .on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('checkAlive', function(d) {
        console.log('>> checkAlive >> '+JSON.stringify(d));
    });
    socket.on('newsTestEmit1', function(d){
        console.log('>> newsTestEmit1 >> '+JSON.stringify(d));
    });
  });
```

client.html

```
<script src="http://localhost:8081/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var chat = io.connect('http://localhost:8081/chat')
    , news = io.connect('http://localhost:8081/news');

  chat.on('connect', function () {
    chat.emit('chatTestEmit1',{msg:'This is the message from client.'});
  });

  news.on('connect', function(){
    news.emit('checkAlive',{msg:'News is alive'});
  });
</script>
```

The log looks like this:

```
   info  - socket.io started
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized 74858017692628057
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/74858017692628057
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client 74858017692628057
   debug - client authorized for
   debug - websocket writing 1::
   debug - client authorized for /chat
   debug - websocket writing 1::/chat
   debug - client authorized for /news
   debug - websocket writing 1::/news
>> chatTestEmit1 >> {"msg":"This is the message from client."}
{ '': [ '74858017692628057' ],
  '/chat': [ '74858017692628057' ],
  '/news': [ '74858017692628057' ] }
   debug - websocket writing 5::/chat:{"name":"newsTestEmit1","args":[{"msg":"This is the message from client."}]}
>> checkAlive >> {"msg":"News is alive"}
   debug - emitting heartbeat for client 74858017692628057
   debug - websocket writing 2::
   debug - set heartbeat timeout for client 74858017692628057
   debug - got heartbeat packet
   debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client 74858017692628057
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client 74858017692628057
   debug - emitting heartbeat for client 74858017692628057
```

If this code worked correctly, it should have logged as below:

```
>> newsTestEmit1 >> {"msg":"This is the message from client."}
```

appeared in the log. Note that I also tried:

```
io.sockets.in('/news').emit('newsTestEmit1', d);
io.sockets.in('news').emit('newsTestEmit1', d);
io.of('/news').emit('newsTestEmit1', d);
```

None of them works. Do I miss something?

Thanks.

Comment: `socket.emit` sends events to clients in the browser, not the server.

Comment: Why do you need server-side cross room events?  There is a socket.io client for node.js but that seems like overkill for this scenario.

Comment: @user80222: I don't agree with you. Many scenarios (e.g the browser compatibility issue that have to dig tunnel in the server, irc has system admin could broadcast msg to any room they want, or pass some private msg to other room for secure connection, etc.) require this feature if it really exists.

Comment: My point is, if you want to send events to new, chat, or both rooms, just do it directly--why the extra indirection of sending an event between rooms?  Or create your own room abstraction that uses events.EventEmitter to communicate.  Use a separate room (that all clients listen to) for broadcast messages.

Answer (score 0):

I did not look through all of your code, but the general idea is that you want to emit an event + the data from the client-side when a message is sent, then set an event on the server-side to broadcast when a happens. Some psuedo server-side code below:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Socket connection established.');
    socket.on('message event', function(data){
      socket.broadcast.emit('global chat update', data);}
      );
});
```

On the client side you want 2 bits of code:

1) When a chat event happens, something like:

```
socket.emit('message event', data)
```

2) Something to display the newest chat when there is a global chat update.

```
socket.on('global chat update', function(data) { // your script to update chat data here };
```